# Does a untrained beginner get muscle mass gains, or strength gains, or both without applying progressive overload?

Tags: beginners, progress

I've read somewhere that they get gains without applying progressive overload.
That would mean one could get bigger muscles without getting stronger, because he doesn't add reps/weight each workout.

Comment: If you start training, that's already progressive overload. Your body will adapt until you are at your new equilibrium

Comment: test @Raditz_35

Comment: I don't get what you are saying. It seems to me like you are basically posting this: "I'm training suboptimally without applying progressive overload and I've noticed that I don't have much success". Well, start training right with progressive overload. I don't think that's interesting, I think that's obvious. Also, please note that those things take time. It's most likely not your body but your impatience and lack of thought put into it and it sounds like you are missing a good program. You will need to train 1-2 years naturally (depending on how old you are) until you can tell

Comment: Usually men don't need to train 1-2 years to see results. @Raditz_35 Probably not even women?

Comment: You will have results a lot earlier, but if you are just about looks, you have to really think long term. There will be changes in under a year, but without taking drugs and ruining your life (it's so dangerous), it won't be that much

Comment: but i was adding reps as form of progressive overload, for 6 long months, training to muscle failure to almost every set. @Raditz_35 my results were almost none compared to the average man.

Comment: So you either are not "average" in some way, don't know what average is, don't eat right, don't train right or a combination. Please post your workout and diet. Btw, don't train to failure on every set, mistake #1

Answer (score 1):

no.. progressive overload isnt absolutely necessary for a newbie. although youll stop gaining after a 3 to 4 weeks and it is highly inefficient.

As a beginner, you'll make gains quickly in both strength and muscle with little effort because your body is suddenly going from couch potato with fatty diet to using your muscles everyday and eating clean.. essentially getting in natural shape. Technically this is progressive overload because your going from doing no exercise, to doing exercise such as bicep curls no weights.. or eve doing exercises with weights such as bicep curls but with 5 lb dumbbells. To answer your question, no. progressive overload is not needed. although your gains will be slower and much less significant and your body will likely stall within a few weeks due to not needing to add muscle or strength to lift the same weights. thats the definition of progressive overload because your body does not need to enhance itself to lift the same weights unless your lifting them for more reps or lifting more weight.

if you do this you will likely not get in shape and gain maybe 2 to 5 lbs at best of muscle.

After 6 months to a year the newbie phase ends and youll have to change your diet and workout. Athough if youre not using progressive overload, your gains will probably stop within a few weeks. I dnt understand why you wouldnt want to increase the weight or add reps unless youre trying to be as lazy as possible with a workout

Answer (score 1):

> That would mean one could get bigger muscles without getting stronger

I think you've got this backwards.

There are two ways in which you get stronger: add more muscle fibres, or, increase your muscle fibre recruitment (i.e. how efficiently you use your muscles).

When you workout without a progressive overload and without eating in a surplus you are increasing your body's ability to recruit muscle fibres. This is the opposite of your statement: *you'll get stronger without getting bigger muscles*.

You said that you trained to failure every day. What did your reps start at, and what did they end at? If you started at 10 and ended at 20 that *is*, by definition, progress.

Comment: See: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2017/why-is-muscle-size-not-proportional-to-strength

Comment: i started with negative chin ups 5 sec down 7x7x7, and after 6 months of a full body workout it was: 8 sec down 5x5x5

Comment: @Stjema: (7+7+7)*5 = 105 seconds total hang time. (5+5+5)*8 = 120 seconds total hang time. It looks like progress to me.

Comment: 6 months.... 6 months. @C. Lange Do you know how much 6 months are? 15 seconds progress... have that in mind...
The avg guy makes 3x12 chin ups after 6 months.

Comment: @Stjema Where do you have this nonsense information from? 3x12 is quite impressive depending on your weight, age and biophysical properties

Comment: Every teen can do at least 5 chin ups if his bf% is under 13. @Raditz_35

Comment: @Stjema I do know quite a lot of people who's bf% is way above 13, and would consider 13% either very well trained or underfed. I also know many people who can't do 1 chinup, let alone 5

Comment: It would probably be easier to discuss this in a chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/324/the-locker-room

Comment: @Stjema You seem to be making up your own facts. If you just state that everyone is better than you, then we cannot help you. If you start having realistic goals and listen to what people (here or elsewhere) are saying, you might have a shot at improving your training

Comment: i am listening always @Raditz_35

Comment: @Stjerna: too much negatives i think. Try this: jump up and do the first chin-up. You can roughly control the help you are getting by adjusting how hard you are jumping. Next lower yourself slowly. "Bump" at the bottom (invoke stretch reflex), pull like crazy and try to get as high up as possible. You will have to do many sets (5-10) and train this 3 times a week.

Comment: As the number of repetitions go up you can decrease the number of sets.